# What are the characters appearing at the end of my appengine URL

Tags: google-app-engine, addthis

I have an appengine Python application.  It includes the simpleauth library.  I am viewing the application in Google Chrome.

After I load a page in the application, some text that looks like (for example) "#.UhJcZ2TwKa4" is appended to the end of the URL.

What is this and where does it come from?

Upon edit, maybe it's one of my javascript includes that is doing it.  Here are all my javascript includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/dvk0ttp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance,

Aaron

Comment: Are you using AddThis?

Comment: I found the answer. Turns out it was AddThis address bar sharing analytics.

Comment: @DevilingMaster If you want to make it an answer, I'd love to accept it.  The include for addthis was in another part of the code and I didn't paste it into the question.  So, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using AddThis APIs and you have enabled address bar tracking which appends those "strange" characters to the page url.

Those parameters are used to collect data if someone copies the URL somewhere else

If you don't want this feature, you can disable it, editing the javascript config variable for the APIs (See attached link for the tutorial)

```
data_track_addressbar = false;
```

Source: [AddThis Support](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381254-address-bar-sharing-analytics)

Answer (score 1):

Inserting: 
`<script type="text/javascript">
        var addthis_config = addthis_config||{};
        addthis_config.data_track_addressbar = false;
        addthis_config.data_track_clickback = false;
    </script>` 
before closing the  tag cleans the URL

This is the corect resource: [Removing all hashtags/anchors from your URLs](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1013558-removing-all-hashtags-anchors-from-your-urls)